How do I connect my S19s with my full node for solo mining?
I am running a full node server and attempting to attach a dozen S19 miners. The Bitcoin Core machine seems to be up and running, fully synced and I can ping it. I also can see it is listening on the port 8332 correctly.
I can not seem to connect a S19 miner correctly.  I have the correct data in the bitcoin.conf file. I am wondering about the next steps for troubleshooting.
